# Obtaining log-odds coefficients instead of proportions in output of post-hoc tests in emmeans package

Tags: r, multinomial-logit, lsmeans, nnet

I got in trouble for posting this on Stack Overflow a few days ago. It seemed to me more of a coding question than a statistical question (i.e. what argument to use in the `emmeans` package to obtain proportions), but the responder had 290k reputation so I will defer to their judgement and post here.

I conducted a multinomial logistic regression examining the difference in log-odds of respondents indicating they treated a range of different medical conditions (`pain`, `sleep`, mental-health/substance use (`mhsu`) and all other conditions (`allOther`)) with either `licit` or `illicit` medical cannabis.

Here is the toy data

```
df <- tibble(mcType = factor(rep(c("licit", "illicit"),
                                 times = c(534,1207))),
             cond = factor(c(rep(c("pain","mhsu","allOther","sleep"), 
                                 times = c(280,141,82,31)),
                             rep(c("pain","mhsu","allOther","sleep"), 
                                 times = c(491,360,208,148))),
                           levels = c("pain","sleep","mhsu","allOther")))
```

And the proportions of each type of condition reported for each type of cannabis (`perc` column is %)

```
mcType  cond         n   tot  perc
<fct>   <fct>    <int> <int> <dbl>
1 illicit pain       491  1207 40.7 
2 illicit sleep      148  1207 12.3 
3 illicit mhsu       360  1207 29.8 
4 illicit allOther   208  1207 17.2 
5 licit   pain       280   534 52.4 
6 licit   sleep       31   534  5.81
7 licit   mhsu       141   534 26.4 
8 licit   allOther    82   534 15.4
```

[image]

Now I want to see whether there are differences in the relative proportion of respondents indicating each type of condition based on the type of cannabis they report using. So I ran a multinomial logistic regression using `multinom()` in the `nnet` package.

```
summary(mm <- multinom(cond ~ mcType,
                       data = df))


# output
Coefficients:
  (Intercept) mcTypelicit
sleep     -1.1992431  -1.0014884
mhsu      -0.3103369  -0.3756443
allOther  -0.8589398  -0.3691759

Std. Errors:
  (Intercept) mcTypelicit
sleep     0.09377333   0.2112368
mhsu      0.06938587   0.1244098
allOther  0.08273132   0.1503720

Residual Deviance: 4327.814 
AIC: 4339.814
```

Now the coefficients for this regression are clearly in log-odds.

Now I want to run test of simple effects. So I turned, as always, to the `emmeans` package

```
# testing effect of mc type at each level of condition
(em_mcTypeByCond <- emmeans(object = mm,
                            specs = ~mcType|cond))

# output
cond = pain:
  mcType    prob      SE df lower.CL upper.CL
illicit 0.4068 0.01414  6   0.3722   0.4414
licit   0.5243 0.02161  6   0.4715   0.5772

cond = sleep:
  mcType    prob      SE df lower.CL upper.CL
illicit 0.1226 0.00944  6   0.0995   0.1457
licit   0.0581 0.01012  6   0.0333   0.0828

cond = mhsu:
  mcType    prob      SE df lower.CL upper.CL
illicit 0.2983 0.01317  6   0.2660   0.3305
licit   0.2641 0.01908  6   0.2174   0.3107

cond = allOther:
  mcType    prob      SE df lower.CL upper.CL
illicit 0.1723 0.01087  6   0.1457   0.1989
licit   0.1535 0.01560  6   0.1154   0.1917

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Now these coefficients are clearly proportions. This is fine, but when I go to actually run the tests using the `pairs()` function

```
(mcTypeByCond_test <- pairs(em_mcTypeByCond)) 
  
  # output
  cond = pain:
  contrast        estimate     SE df t.ratio p.value
illicit - licit  -0.1175 0.0258  6 -4.551  0.0039 

cond = sleep:
  contrast        estimate     SE df t.ratio p.value
illicit - licit   0.0646 0.0138  6  4.665  0.0034 

cond = mhsu:
  contrast        estimate     SE df t.ratio p.value
illicit - licit   0.0342 0.0232  6  1.476  0.1905 

cond = allOther:
  contrast        estimate     SE df t.ratio p.value
illicit - licit   0.0188 0.0190  6  0.987  0.3616
```

The coefficients also seem to be in differences in proportions, *not* log-odds.

So my question is **are these propotions, and, if so, how do I get the coefficients reported in log-odds?**.

I have tried searching the web for answers but have come up with nothing. I tried adding the argument `type = "response"` but it had no discernible effect on the output. It seems to be very automatic behaviour to me so I'm wondering if there isn't some interaction between `nnet::multinom()` and `emmeans` that I am not aware of: emmeans is compatible with so many packages it's hard to find any info and The help for `?summary.emmGrid` is no help, at least not to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can look in [`vignette("models", "emmeans")`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html) and refer to `multinom` objects, and you will find that the default for these models is to output estimated probabilities. So that answers the first part of your question.

The second part is to re-define the object as if it were on the logit scale. That is done via the `regrid()` function.

```r
new_emm <- regrid(em_mcTypeByCond, transform = "logit")
pairs(new_emm)
```

Or, if you want the ratios themselves, do `pairs(new_emm, type = "response")`; the tests themselves will be identical, as they will still be done on the log scale (differences of logits are considered to be on the log scale).

Also, if you do `confint(new_emm, type = "response")`, you will see the estimated probabilities as before.

See `? regrid` for details on re-gridding

Comment: Brilliant @Russ Lenth, `regrid()` was exactly what I was looking for, thank you.